# Does scrollWidth change with div width?

Tags: jquery, css

First question: should the scrollWidth value ever really change if the content inside doesn't change but the div width does (say on a window resize event)? I would think it shouldn't, but then I'm not sure why I'm having the problems I'm having.

If it *should* change, then I'm having issues with the scrollWidth not updating to the correct value when the div width changes.

I have a div that sets the width of another div (via jQuery) to the scrollWidth. There is a panel that sits next to the parent div that opens and closes, changing the parent div's width depending on whether it's open or closed. The scrollWidth of the parent div does not appear to change when this panel is open or closed (which makes some sense to me), but on something like a window resize event, the child div who's width is set to the scrollwidth of the parent div does not resize appropriately and instead overflows the parent div (see picture). The scrollWidth property only seems to change when the parent element is turned on/off (with the `#openAttrTable` button in my case) and the panel being on or off the screen affects what width the parent div is instantiated with.

**Basically, I need the scrollWidth property to update every time the parent div width is changed even if the parent div has already been instantiated.**

Multiple buttons control opening of the side panel, opening of the attribute table, and then setting the scroll width depending on what's open. You'll notice that on click of `#display-map-info` I had to manually add and subtract pixels from scrollWidth to get the drag bar to fill the space appropriately, I'm not sure why just setting it to scrollWidth doesn't work. If I don't subtract the pixels, the drag-bar will overflow the div and overlap the layers panel (see picture).

```
//Creates the slide out animation for the layers panel
$('#display-map-info').click(function () {
    $('#map-functions').toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);
    $('#map-functions').toggleClass("visible");
    //If attribute table is already open and layers panel is opening on this click
    if ($("#attribute-table").hasClass("open") && $("#map-functions").hasClass("visible")) {
        $("#attribute-table").animate({ width: '-=250px' }, 500);
        //Set drag-bar width and animate with opening of layers panel
        var width = $("#attribute-table")[0].scrollWidth;
        $("#attrTable-handle").css("width", width);
        $("#attrTable-handle").animate({ width: '-=250px' }, 500);
    }
    //If only attribute table is open
    else if ($("#attribute-table").hasClass("open")) {
        $("#attribute-table").animate({ width: '+=250px' }, 500);
        //Set drag-bar width
        var width = $("#attribute-table")[0].scrollWidth + 250;
        $("#attrTable-handle").css("width", width);
    }
});
//Open attribute table on button click, set the width based on whether the layers panel is open or not
$("#openAttrTable").click(function () {
    if ($("#map-functions").hasClass("visible")) {
        $("#attribute-table").css("width", "100%").css("width", "-=300px");
        $("#attribute-table").toggleClass("open");
        $("#attribute-table").toggle();
        //Set drag-bar width
        var width = $("#attribute-table")[0].scrollWidth;
        $("#attrTable-handle").css("width", width);
    }
    else {
        $("#attribute-table").css("width", "100%").css("width", "-=50px");
        $("#attribute-table").toggleClass("open");
        $("#attribute-table").toggle();
        //Set drag-bar width
        var width = $("#attribute-table")[0].scrollWidth;
        $("#attrTable-handle").css("width", width);
    }
});

//When window resizes, resize attribute table based on whether layers panel is open or not
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($("#map-functions").hasClass("visible") && $("#attribute-table").hasClass("open")) {
        $("#attribute-table").css("width", "100%").css("width", "-=300px");
        //Set drag-bar width
        var width = $("#attribute-table")[0].scrollWidth;
        $("#attrTable-handle").css("width", width);
    }
    else if ($("#attribute-table").hasClass("open")) {
        $("#attribute-table").css("width", "100%").css("width", "-=50px");
        //Set drag-bar width
        var width = $("#attribute-table")[0].scrollWidth;
        $("#attrTable-handle").css("width", width);
    }
});
```

[image]

```
#map-functions {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 250px;
  top: 115px;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 9px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 5px solid orange;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#attribute-table {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    height: 250px;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    top: auto !important;
    padding-top: 7px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 31;
}

#attrTable-handle {
    height: 5px;
    background-color: orange;
    top: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="visible" id="map-functions"></div>
<div id="attribute-table">
   <div id="attrTable-handle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around by just using the `.width()` method. I didn't realize that this method would return the whole width of the div and not just what was visible on the screen, so it is very similar to `scrollWidth` but updates consistently instead of only in certain instances.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($("#map-functions").hasClass("visible") && $("#attribute-table").hasClass("open")) {
        $("#attribute-table").css("width", "100%").css("width", "-=300px");
        //Set drag-bar width
        var width = $("#attribute-table").width();
        $("#attrTable-handle").css("width", width);
    }
    else if ($("#attribute-table").hasClass("open")) {
        $("#attribute-table").css("width", "100%").css("width", "-=50px");
        //Set drag-bar width
        var width = $("#attribute-table").width();
        $("#attrTable-handle").css("width", width);
    }
});
```